# Php captcha session variable not found

Tags: php, jquery, session, captcha

I have this `captcha.php` file that I load on the page I want the captcha to appear on using jQuery load.

In the `captcha.php` file I start a new session and I set a variable (`theCaptchaCode`) which contains the code you see on the image, but when I try to get the session variable with `$theCaptchaCode = $_SESSION['theCaptchaCode']`. It says

> undefined index: theCaptchaCode.

Captcha.php code:

```
<?php
    //Killing previous session
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
?>
<?php
    session_start();
    $theCaptchaCode = "";
    $thisCaptchaImg = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($thisCaptchaImg, 0, 0, 0);
    $dotColor = imagecolorallocate($thisCaptchaImg, 46, 46, 46);
    $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($thisCaptchaImg, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefilledrectangle($thisCaptchaImg, 0, 0, 200, 70, $backgroundColor);
    $characters = '123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
    $length = strlen($characters);
    for ($l = 0; $l < 4; $l++)
    {
        imageline($thisCaptchaImg, 0, rand() % 50, 200, rand() % 50, $color);
    }
    for ($d = 0; $d < 1500; $d++)
    {
        imagesetpixel($thisCaptchaImg, rand() % 200, rand() % 50, $dotColor);
    }
    for ($c = 0; $c < 7; $c++)
    {
        $selCharacter = $characters[rand(0, $length - 1)];
        imagestring($thisCaptchaImg, 5, 5 + ($c * 30), 20, $selCharacter, $color);
        $theCaptchaCode .= $selCharacter;
    }
    imagepng($thisCaptchaImg, 'thisCaptchaImage.png');
    $_SESSION['theCaptchaCode'] = $theCaptchaCode;
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your code remove the `session_destroy()` method.

**Edited:** 
Use the below code:

```
<?php session_start();
$theCaptchaCode = "";
$thisCaptchaImg = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);
$color = imagecolorallocate($thisCaptchaImg, 0, 0, 0);
$dotColor = imagecolorallocate($thisCaptchaImg, 46, 46, 46);
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($thisCaptchaImg, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($thisCaptchaImg, 0, 0, 200, 70, $backgroundColor);
$characters = '123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
$length = strlen($characters);
for($l=0;$l < 4;$l++)
{
    imageline($thisCaptchaImg, 0, rand()%50, 200, rand()%50, $color);
}
for($d=0;$d < 1500;$d++)
{
    imagesetpixel($thisCaptchaImg, rand()%200, rand()%50, $dotColor);
}
for($c=0;$c < 7;$c++)
{
    $selCharacter = $characters[rand(0, $length-1)];
    imagestring($thisCaptchaImg, 5, 5+($c*30), 20, $selCharacter, $color);
    $theCaptchaCode .= $selCharacter;
}
imagepng($thisCaptchaImg, 'thisCaptchaImage.png');
$_SESSION['theCaptchaCode'] = $theCaptchaCode;
?>
```

Comment: Now i get Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: @Jojo01, only have one session_start() at the start of the page and remove all other session functions from your code because of every session_start and destroy you are resetting the session.

Comment: I have put only one session_start() at the beginning of the page where the captcha appears but i get again: Undefined index: theCaptchaCode

Comment: Undefined index: theCaptchaCode ,is this error coming on this same page or on another page?, also another suggestion put the session start exactly one space after the `<?php` tag. If it is coming on another page then on that page also you need to put `session_start()` at the top one space after the ` <?php` tag.

Comment: On the same page when i try to get the content of the variable to check if it corresponds with what the user entered.

Comment: are you having htaccess?

Comment: I use this on a local apache server. It is provided by usbwebserver: http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/

Comment: i just ran on my local apache server and it works fine, i got `IG4N1PU` as output, do one thing close and open browser and try to run code again to refresh session

Comment: The thing here is that i check if what the user has written corresponds with the captcha on the page where the captcha appears.

Comment: ok then start the session on the other page as well, i can say that this part of code that you have posted works fine

Comment: if possible pack and send me the total project, i will debug and give you

Comment: Seems to me like the only option is to directly paste the code into the page where the captcha appears instead of using jQuery.

Comment: I do not have access to your code completly so i am not in position to tell much about your decision